# How to make Kendo Grid Column auto Width

Tags: kendo-grid

I used jQuery plugin datatables, which will auto width columns to fetch the title or data content length if we don't specify the column width of the Grid.

Now I want the same function in Kendo Grid, however, I cannot find it except make Grid wrapper style fixed and set a col width css for all columns, which make the small length field also take big space.

So my question is how to make the Kendo Grid column (usually I have many fields, and it is scroll-able) auto width or in different length (and I don't expect to set width for each column manually).

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

You kind of have to set the width when you define the columns , if you don't specify the width then it will take the auto-width of the content.
**Take a look at this DOC** http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.width

```
columns: [
     { field: "name", width: "200px" },
     { field: "tel", width: "10%" }, // this will set width in % , good for responsive site
     { field: "age" } // this will auto set the width of the content 
   ],
```

If you need more ways to handle Kendo width, look at http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/web/grid/walkthrough#column-widths

Answer (score 8):

Setting scrollable to false should do the trick:

```
$('#grid').kendoGrid({
  dataSource: {
     data: data
  },
  scrollable: false,
  resizable: true
});
```

Comment: Because if you put " scrollable:false " , the horizontal scroll that appears when you resize if your total columns width is bigger than the screen width, won't appear and the children will be forced to fit into the parent. So, " scrollable:false " modify the way kendo grid is build. If you don't put it, the parent width is calculated by the children width.

Answer (score 5):

i'm also solve this issue in angular with dataBound :

my issue about kendo auto fit columns in databound

```
        <kendo-grid id="grid" options="mainGridOptions">
        </kendo-grid>



        dataBound: function(){
            var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
            for (var i = 0; i < grid.columns.length; i++) {
                grid.autoFitColumn(i);
            }
        },
        dataSource: $scope.data,
```

you can do it in jquery:

```
$('#grid').kendoGrid({
  dataSource: {
     data: data
  },dataBound: function(){
            var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
            for (var i = 0; i < grid.columns.length; i++) {
                grid.autoFitColumn(i);
            }
        },
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but this is available since 2015 Q1.

Comment: @federico embed one line config? Without js function? How?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not an easy way, you need to get the max length like select max(len(col1)) as len1 from X table of every column and later preset the width for each of them somehow with Pixels, I'm still working on the equation, but yeah it can work even in old versions like 2014 or earlier.